# Serve /blog from a different url in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

My website also has a blog and the blog is hosted on a different server.

How can I serve the blog from that server using .htaccess?

So for example `www.example.com/blog/` should serve files from `www.othersite.com/` without changing the url.

Tried something like this, but i'm getting 404:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.othersite.com/  [L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that will work. `RewriteEngine` will rewrite the path of the url, not the entire url. Why would you want to do this? This is very bad for seo purposes.

Comment: The only way you would be able to do this is by setting up a proxy to that other website.

Comment: Do you have a domain name from where it redirects to `www.othersite.com`?

Comment: @Perumal93 yes I have. I've been reading about reverse proxies, maybe that will help?

Comment: @Jerodev the proxy can be set up from .htaccess?

Comment: No, you need to change this in your apache config. I do not know how to do this exactly myself as I use nginx.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about proxy workings in this case. http://serverfault.com/questions/130694/how-can-i-redirect-urls-using-the-proxy-module-in-apache. Check out this post. You might get some idea about it.

Comment: I think the link I mentioned above in the comment is what you're exactly looking for.

Comment: I can think in other options instead of using .htaccess
Option 1:
HTML iframe covering width 100% and height 100% of the browser. But won't work well in mobile, and the url in the browser will be static.
Option 2: Give access to the database from the server www.othersite.com to the server example.com. All the blog files need to be on both servers, but content will be the same in the database of www.othersite.com.

Comment: @Perumal93 yes, I think it does the right thing. thanks (you can submit as an awnser)

Comment: I can't submit suggestion as an answer unless I'm at least quite sure about the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that this can't be done. If this could be done then what would there be to stop me hosting http://mywebsite.com/my-awesome-article and simply ripping someone else off by using their content as part of my site?

Comment: but I have control of that other website. maybe there should be a way to whitelist?

Comment: Even if you could, why would you want to? SEO-nightmare if ever I saw one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/blog(.*)$ http://www.othersite.com$1  [L,QSA]
```